# Django URL dispatcher example - pass url from view to another

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

Anyone have a quick url dispatcher example? I've looked at the Django documentation but I find that there isn't a complete example that shows you how everything is working in the views.

Specifically, I'm trying to pass the "url" from one view to another. For example, I am trying to make a holiday website: if a button in "available holidays" view called "europe" is clicked, I want to go to www.example.com/selected/europe, where all european holidays are displayed
while if a button in the available holidays view called "Australia" is clicked, I want to go to www.example.com/selected/australia where similarly australian holidays are displayed.

So far, in url.py I have:

```
(r'^selected/(?P<location>\w+)/$', 'app.views.selected'),
```

in views.py I have:

```
def selected(request, location)
```

I'm not sure where to go from there. 
Also, how are things going to move from the "available holidays" view to the "selected" view...

Comment: This question is very unclear. What do you mean, "where to go from there"? You have successfully passed the location parameter into your view. What else do you need?

Comment: i'm mainly confused about how the button selected in a different view is going to be passed into the selected view..

Comment: Hi Johnny, you'll learn a lot by answering other peoples questions occasionally. Try it sometime. You're 23-0 at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the "available holidays" template, you should link to the locations page.

First, add a "name" argument to your url definition:

```
(r'^selected/(?P<location>\w+)/$', 'app.views.selected', name='selected_holidays'),
```

Then, in the "available holidays" templates, link as such:

```
{% url selected_holidays 'Europe' %}
```

Of course, use the location variable if in a forloop:

```
{% for location in locations %}
    <a href="{% url selected_holidays location %}">{{ location }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

If location is a model, then you should add a get_absolute_url method to the model e.g.:

```
from django.core import urlresolvers

class Location(models.Model):
    # ... [snip]
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return urlresolvers.reverse('selected_holidays', args=(self.location_name,))
```

Then in the template:

```
{% for location in locations %}
    <a href="{{ location.get_absolute_url }}">{{ location }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

In that case, change the name of the url from 'selected_holidays' to 'location_detail' if it makes sense - that's quite a standard in Django.

**If** you want to be forward compatible, load the future url tag as such:

```
{% load url from future %}
```

Then, use a named url string with quotes:

```
{% url 'selected_holidays' 'Europe' %}
```

Well I think you got some starters here. You should also overread Django urls manual to know where's what in case of troubble :) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation. I feel that your answer deserves more recognition than it received.